# Problem passing time from Angular to C # Core

Tags: c#, angular, time

The problem is to pass an hour value through an observable method (Angular 8) to a controller (C # Core 2.2), at the time of sending data is correct:

[image]

However, when I receive the values, it is automatically added +3 hours:

[image]

I'm currently running localhost, what better approach to solve the timezone problem globally? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Use UTC to store the time, then handle conversion on the client side?

Comment: I can't tell what the question is here? Are you asking what a UTC is or asking why your C# code doesn't know what it is?

Comment: I would like C # to receive the time I'm passing without adding +3

Comment: Since I see GMT coming from the client I assume that the server is then in a different timezone. As suggested by @grooveplex have the server handle the code in UTC. What if another client was in a different timezone again?

Comment: I must be missing something here, I need C # to get the value I'm passing and store it exactly

Answer (score -1):

You can try convert your Dates to timestamp in your js/ts code.

```
const timeinmiliseconds = YourTimeObject.getTime()
```

Then in your c# code ,

```
 System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
 dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds( timeinmiliseconds /1000 );
```